# Android : BluetoothSocket and InputStream.available()

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

I want to check whether the BluetoothSocket is open for operation or not.....
Here is what I do:

First of all I get an InputStream from my BluetoothSocket, I want to perform some operation with that InputStream, if an IOException occurs my program can determine that socket is disconnected..... And after making sure that socket is connected I want to read some data from it.

For making sure I am calling `available()` which by default returns 0 or a number of bytes.... if return value is 0 my reading operation throws IOException.

Here are my questions.

1. Is `available()` blocking I/O call or an asynchronous one?
2. Return value >0 only when I give some input from my device while connecting, which will not always be the case. Am I doing any mistake allowing to read if there are 0 available bytes? How to avert this?

Answer (score 0):

First u have to connect with a Bluetooth server. Use connect() to connect, this method will block until a connection is made or the connection fails (resulting in an exception). So make sure to run this on a separate thread.

```
public void run() {
    try {

        socket.connect();

                    InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                   //socket connected, inputStream can be used 
                   //Bluetooth
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Socket is refused connection with the server.
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the question once again.......... Try to read and understand properly......

Comment: if your socket.connect() succeeds  your Bluetooth socket is ready to read and send bytes. To read bytes u have to send some bytes from the server, which i don't think your doing. If you calling available() without sending any bytes available() will return 0. Post the exception your get here.